# Header from response using isomorphic-fetch

Tags: http-headers, rails-api

I'm getting a successful response (200) with all the body data but the header is empty. The response header has an access-token that I need for future requests. When I try it with curl or postman I can see the headers, but isomorphic-fetch gets me an empty header.

```
fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: data})
.then(checkStatus)
.then(response => response.headers ); // response.json() gets me body data
```

Is anybody retrieving headers successfully with isomorphic-fetch?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. The client wasn't the problem. Custom headers require extra configuration when doing CORS. Issue was on the server because my API was missing one line of configuration:

```
headers: :any,
expose:  ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'], # Was missing this line.
methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
```